# How to get a Text to the left of an input field

Tags: html, css, forms, contacts

This might be a very simple question, but somehow I can't solve it by myself.

I have a contact form, and I want to Display the title of the inputfield on the right and the input on the left like:

Name: [input]

HTML:

```
  <main>
    <div class="contact_form">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/php/action_page.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name" style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">Vorname:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
            >
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse... "
            />
            <textarea
              id="subject"
              name="subject"
              placeholder="Deine Nachricht..."
              style="height: 200px;"
            ></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```

CSS:

```
.contact_form {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  
input[type="text"],
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical; 
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  
  border: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container p {
  color: white;
  font-family: PTS;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

You can find the contact form under: http://charlyscarface.com/problem/

I tried putting the lable and inputfield in one div, but it is still displayed in two rows.

Might be, that I am overseeing some display declaration or something.

Comment: You set your input text width = 100%. Nothing else is going to fit on the same line then.

Comment: Your are using input width as 100 percent change it to 90% it' ll work

Comment: Were I able to solve your doubt? if yes, then kindly accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the silly mistake is that you have specified -

```
input[type="text"],
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

here width: 100% is preventing both of them to come in same line as the input is only taking the 100 percent of the screen... By the way I have currently omitted that but you can again specify it according to your need like 80% or 60% just as you like.

```css
.contact_form {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  
input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical; 
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  
  border: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container p {
  color: white;
  font-family: PTS;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="contact_form">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/php/action_page.php" method="POST">
            <label for="name" style="text-align: left;">Vorname:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
            />
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse... "
            />
            <textarea
              id="subject"
              name="subject"
              placeholder="Deine Nachricht..."
              style="height: 200px;"
            ></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if I was able to solve your doubt and Run code snippet for your desired results

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add a parent HTML element to each of your label and input combo, so you may arrange them with flex :

```css
.form-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* optionnal */
  gap: 12px; /* optionnal */
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <p class="form-line">
     <label for="your-input">label</label>
     <input type="text" id="your-input">
 </p>
```

Width: 100% on your input could be useful in other contexts of your project so, you may want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a div with `display: flex` and `max-width: 100%` around the input and the label and set `flex-grow` at the input to 1

```css
.contact_form {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1/4;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }


.name-container{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
}

label{margin-right: .3rem}

input[type="text"],
select {
flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical; 
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{
    width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  
  border: solid black 2px; 
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%; 
  padding: 12px; 
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  margin-top: 6px; 
  margin-bottom: 16px; 
  resize: vertical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container p {
  color: white;
  font-family: PTS;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="contact_form">
        <div class="container">
          <form action="/php/action_page.php" method="POST">
            <div class="name-container">
            <label for="name" style="display: inline-block; text-align: left;">Vorname:</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              name="name"
            >
            </div>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              name="email"
              placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse... "
            />
            <textarea
              id="subject"
              name="subject"
              placeholder="Deine Nachricht..."
              style="height: 200px;"
            ></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
  </main>
```